# Why does the function have to need return two boolean to avoid an error?

Tags: java

i'm sorry this problem is simple but keeps frustrating me. I'm really appreciate that if you could tell me the reasons.
ps,it's homework2 of cs61b.
i need to check if a year is a leapyear,but obviously the boolean method only needs to return one boolean value (true or false) 
since i add another return code line, the compiler error has gone. I really don't understand why, the brackets is in the right place.

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if ((year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || year%400=0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the `if` evaluates to `false`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: You're better off with `return ((year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || year%400=0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to return one `boolean` (you can't return two), but you must provide a `return` statement for each possible scenario, both for if-condition is true, and if-condition is false.

Comment: actually, the compiler complained because there is only a return statement in case the if-condition returned true. in the other case, the method wouldn't return anything, while the return type demands that a boolean is returned (unless an Exception is thrown)

Answer (score 0):

Your program returns true if it is a leap year, else... nothing

```
 public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if ((year%4&&year%100!=0)||year%400==0)
            return true; 
        else
           return false;
    }
```

Or you can return an evaluation like :

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year%4&&year%100!=0)||year%400==0);
}
```

(which a better way to do it)

Comment: the else statement is a bit redundant, since if the condition is true, the method stops at the first return statement.

Comment: OFC it is but @陈艺夫  has a huge lack of knowledge in programmation. I just tried to explain it so he understand

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not define what to return when your `if` condition evaluates to `false`. Here's a shorter version:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    return ((year%4==0 && year%100==0)||year%400==0);
}
```